# Gather verb acts like Say, drops call after speaking / action URL is valid

Tags: twilio-api

I'm at a loss as I can't see any reason why Twilio is not handling this correctly, and I've tried tweaking it like crazy... I have a voice reponse which I send back as a before returning it back to Twilio... which actually may be the problem.. but due to seralization of voice reponse is an issue, I have to send it back to the controller as a string, and then from the controller back to twilio....

Here is the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Gather action="http://xxxx.ngrok.io/api/Voice/CallService" method="POST" numDigits="1">
    <Say voice="Polly.Carmen"></Say>
    <Say>blah, blah, blah</Say>
    <Say>Please press 0 followed by the pound sign</Say>
    <Pause length="5"></Pause>
  </Gather>
  <Say>We didn't receive any input. Goodbye!</Say>
</Response>
```

I generate that XML via this code using the C# library:

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
      var callServices = new Uri(xxxxConfiguration.GetConfigurations[EnvironmentVariables.xxxxCallServices]);

      var gather = new Gather(
                              action: callServices,
                              method: Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post,
                              numDigits: 1
                              );

      gather
        .Say(voice: Say.VoiceEnum.PollyCarmen)
        .Say("blah, blah, blah")
        .Say("Please press 0 followed by the pound sign")
        ;

      response.Append(gather); //if gathered, the post occurs in the gather..otherwise it falls through to this final comment
      response.Say("We didn't receive any input. Goodbye!");

      return response.ToString();
```

Comment: Brain fart - the reponse was going back as a content type of plain text, and neede to go back as XML ... rather than simply return the string, i created TwiMLResult and feed the string in via the constructor... argh!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio was not responding, as the response was using the content-type of : text/plain.  I used the C# Sdk return type of: new TwiMLResult("XML delivered as a string");